# Django ошибка при логине через соцсети

Tags: django

Стал разбираться во фреймворке Django, решил сначала сделать регистрацию на сайте через соцсети с помощью django-rest-framework-social-oauth2.При миграции БД возникает такая ошибка,в чем может быть проблема?

ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'socialoauth2_provider'

Comment: В сеттингах добавили socialoauth2_provider в INSTALLED_APPS ? В окружении есть этот пакет?

Comment: Сначала стоит освоить в должной мере Python, потом руководство Django и только после этого браться за DRF и какие-либо другие задачи.

Comment: В установленные приложения он вписан, virtualenv не пользуюсь (